# SQL get less than 'date' records in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to get the records from database in codeigniter which has the less than 'date' values than the given date. I used this code and it give me nothing

```
$this->db->select('id, name');

$this->db->where('earliest_date_to_finish > ',$givenDate);

$query = $this->db->get('tasks');
```

The problem is in the where clause . Please suggest me a way to solve this

Comment: whats output you are getting and also tell whats your input.

Comment: $givenData=2013-08-13

Answer (score 1):

you forgot this line

```
     $this->db->from('your_table');
```

Comment: No this is not need  $query = $this->db->get('tasks'); do this job

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->db->where('earliest_date_to_finish > ',$givenDate);
```

Try this

```
$this->db->where('earliest_date_to_finish < ',$givenDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->select('id, name');


$this->db->where('earliest_date_to_finish > ',$date);



$query = $this->db->get('tasks');
```

This code wokris fine now... But it was bit slow.. that was the reason for the problem

Comment: If that query is slow, it probably means you are missing an index on the `earliest_date_to_finish` column.

Comment: The code you've posted appears to be the same as what's in the question, except for the date variable name! Was @Nitish's answer correct maybe?