# Codeigniter where() method with less than comparison

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord, where-clause, comparison-operators

I want execute this query like

```
UPDATE `eventinfo` SET `Status` = '0' WHERE `EventDatetime`< `2015-05-12 01:17:23`.
```

I tried it in different ways like this

```
$whereClause = 'EventDatetime'.'<'.$check_date;
$this->db->where($whereClause);
```

but I failed.What is the correct way.

Comment: You need quotes around dates in that format.

Comment: This should be `$this->db->where('EventDatetime < ',$check_date);`Make sure a space before `<` sign.But I always follow space before and after.

Comment: Oh! i just forget to provide space between 'EventDatetime < ' . By the way thanks it's worked.

Comment: Added as the answer, and you shouldn't actually need a space between `EventDatetime` and `<` as long as `<` is not inside the backticks.

Comment: @Uueerdo The answer you provided should be comment.And are you sure no  need an space to CI active record?Did you ever tried that?

Comment: @ShaifulIslam, I haven't worked with CodeIgniter; but since I would assume (due to the `mysql` tag) it is doing little more than passing the query through to MySQL.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL get less than 'date' records in Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18811109/sql-get-less-than-date-records-in-codeigniter)

Answer (score 2):

Different way to do this :

```
$data = array( 'status' => '0',  );

$this->db->where('EventDatetime <', '2015-05-12 01:17:23');
$this->db->update('eventinfo', $data);
```

Comment: Can you post the error or be more specific to where is the problem ?

Comment: the problem is in creating array

Comment: @saty Why? What's wrong with the array creation code?

Comment: the problem is last comma of array

Comment: @saty, [no that's perfectly fine.](http://artlung.com/blog/2007/01/24/trailing-commas-in-an-array-ok-in-php/)

Comment: I have tested and it works. I use CI3 but on CI2 is the same. In all my array I do like that if I need to add more to the array ... Can't duplicate your error.

Comment: @Mischa i have tested with last comma array it is working fine .Thanks for your important information. But still problem in query i think the column name is EventDatetime not eventdatetime

Answer (score 1):

Using codeigniter way for less then and greater then

```
$this->db->set('Status',0);
$this->db->where('EventDatetime <', '2015-05-12 01:17:23');
$this->db->update('eventinfo');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need quotes around dates in that format.

```
UPDATE `eventinfo` 
SET `Status` = '0' 
WHERE `EventDatetime`< '2015-05-12 01:17:23'
;
```

Comment: You should at least add the code line with the proper way to write it. This answer as it is may get deleted as it looks very much like a comment.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it

```
$data = array( 'Status' => '0',  );

$this->db->where('EventDatetime <', '2015-05-12 01:17:23');
$this->db->update('eventinfo', $data);
```

**NOTE:**

Note the space between '`EventDatetime`' and '`<`', if there is no space, you will get an error

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways to do so

```
$data = array( 'status' => '0',  );
$whereClass="eventdatetime < '2015-05-12 01:17:23'";
$this->db->where($whereClass,NULL,FALSE);
  //or $this->db->where('eventdatetime < ' ,'2015-05-12 01:17:23');
$this->db->update('eventinfo', $data);
```

if still got error then there must database error ,may be a missing record or something